# search n replace nth line in a file

Tags: sed

appreciate if anyone can help me to do so. what i want to achieve is - in file called test.conf file consist with multiple paragraphs. First search for the word "Full" in that para, if found then go to the 3rd line of that paragraph then find and replace word "old" to "NEW". Have a look in example but in 2nd Paragraph i don't want to replace "old" to "NEW" because first condition, the word "Full" doesn't exist in that paragraph. Right after that in 3rd paragraph need to replace "old" to "NEW" because both condition exists.

in other way if first search pattern "Full" and second pattern "old" both found then replace 2nd pattern "old" with "NEW" otherwise do nothing

cat test.conf

```
       description
        server1
        group members
        User CMF **Full** 
        cont_Bred,cont_Hery,cont_Josh
        a,b,c,d
        **old**!text!user_CMF!CMF


        description
        server1
        group members
        User CMF Half 
        cont_Bred,cont_Hery,cont_Josh
        a,b,c,d
        old!text!user_CMF!CMF


        description
        server1
        group members
        User HTP **Full** 
        cont_Bred,cont_Hery,cont_Josh
        a,b,c,d
        **old**!text!user_HTP!HTP
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the tricks:

```
lineNums=$(grep -n "Full" test | cut -d: -f1); for lineNum in $lineNums; do targetLine=$(($lineNum+3)); sed -i "${targetLine}s/old/NEW/" test; done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Simon and appreciate your help. i was looking for sed only command without for loop. For example i managed to replace old to NEW in next line after Full using below command but cant figure out n+3 line. see below  - 

sed -i '/Full/  {n;s/old/NEW/}' test

if i use +3 instated of n, didn't work - any idea how to do using a single liner